# Why is Elizabeth invisible?

Tags: bioshock-infinite

I have been playing Bioshock: Infinite for the past few days, but I am not exactly satisfied with my gameplay. I am about half an hour past grabbing Shock Jockey and, well, the lead female Elizabeth since then has been invisible. I am 100% sure that she is invisible, because in combat I get health packs and ammo thrown at me from an invisible by-stander.

Am I the ony person occurring this issue? I really like the model of Elizabeth as she actually has a perfect body, and to be honest, I am starting to miss her prescense (even though she still is there).

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Yes. We're going to need more information, and even given such information, I can't guarantee anything. System, graphical settings, have you tried quitting and restarting the game? I'm certain this is a bug, I have no idea at this point how to fix it.

Comment: This happened once to me too. It happened to me at [The Hall of Heroes (Going There)](http://www.ign.com/wikis/bioshock-infinite/The_Hall_of_Heroes_(Going_There)) level. I found myself talking to the ghost of Elizabeth. The issue was later fixed. As I continued with the game, Elizabeth became visible again. As a sidenote, I prefer the [original title of your question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/revisions/112561/1). =)

Answer (score 1):

Try lowering or raising the graphical settings to min/max, maybe it'll cause enough stuff to be reloaded that Elizabeth will be rendered again.